# Variável retorna NULL - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando o laravel 5.6 juntamente com o [AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE).
Quando vou realizar o login ele está me retornando o erro

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Indicando a view *page.blade.php*, no trecho

```
 <div class="pull-left info text-center">                    
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->name}}</p>
    <p>Crc {{ Auth::user()->crc}}</p>
 </div>
```

Tentei usar a classe auth()->user()->name, mas ocorre o mesmo problema.

Model *Users*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email','cpf', 'crc', 'password', 'cep', 'endereco', 'numero',
    'bairro', 'cidade',
   ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'cpf', 'crc',
   ];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas a tentar obter propriedades de um utilizador que **não existe** (não logado), para resolver **tens de verificar se o utilizador está logado** exemplo:

```
 <div class="pull-left info text-center">
    @if(Auth::check())                 
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->name}}</p>
    <p>Crc {{ Auth::user()->crc}}</p>
    @endif
 </div>
```

Ou seja, ele só vai fazer *output* desses dois parágrafos quando o utilizador estiver logado.

Comment: Vou testar aqui, vlw!

Comment: Depois de um bom tempo pensando e revisando o código verifiquei que era problemas nas rotas.